# Scripting in C# in Vscode - no code suggestion in .csx files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I've been wanting to write simple scripts for algorithm work with VScode in C#. I came across `dotnet-script` for this.

the problem so far I'm having is that I get not code formatting, suggestions or intellisense when coding in my `.cs` or `.csx` files. Is that normal?

I've installed all required C# extensions for VSCode I believe: C#, C# Dev Kit, and also .NET Install Tool.

Comment: Define "all required C# extensions".

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: Do you have a .csproj file?

Comment: No, the point of dotnet-script is to just write some scripts in c#. Just inside a .cs or .csx file.

Comment: I know. But vs code may have a problem with that.